# JavaScript: How to print all Keys and Values from Array of Arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array of Array in JS as:

```
var myArray = new Array();

myArray[["abc1"]["efg1"]] = 123;

myArray[["abc1"]["efg2"]] = 124;
```

How do I print all Keys and all Values from Array above? 
Expected result is:

```
abc1 efg1 123
abc1 efg2 124
```

I can print value 123 with this: 
`alert(myArray[["abc1"]["efg1"]]);`
I tried printing `alert(myArray.length);` but it shows length is 0, not sure why so can not loop by using length. Any ideas?

Comment: This: `myArray[["abc1"]["efg1"]] = 123;` is not a valid way to set values

Comment: That initial code you have won't run.  You have to make it an array of arrays before you can start assigning properties to it.  Plus, if you want named properties, you probably should be using an object, not an array.  Arrays are also objects, but the `.length` property on an array only applies to the numeric property named elements starting with `0`.  It doesn't count other named properties.

Comment: `console.log(myArray);` and you will see why it is wrong

Comment: You cannot do "associative arrays" in JavaScript. What you are referring to are probably objects. So you are talking of object trees here I assume.

Comment: Please back up and edit your question to include a data structure that would actually run and work in Javascript.  As your question stands now, it's an impossible piece of code that won't run and thus a non-sense question unless we try to guess what you actually meant.  Voting to close as "Unclear What You're Asking" since the question is non-sensical in its current form.

Comment: Thanks 'jfriend00' and 'cars10' !!! Your input means a lot for my direction in learning..

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you have an object like

```
var a={abc:{efg:[123,124]}}
```

you could do the following:

```
for (n in a) 
  for (m in a[n]) 
    a[n][m].forEach(function(v,i){console.log(n,m,i,v);})
```

to get the output:

```
abc efg 0 123
abc efg 1 124
```

But, as I said above, I am only assuming ....

This is an output function that will work for this particular object structure. If you are not certain about the object you want to print you will probably be better off using something like

```
JSON.stringify(a)
```

This way you will get you the complete object structure in JSON format

```
{"abc":{"efg":[123,124]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an object, the you could iterate over the keys and check whether the value is an object, then iterate over that object. if not, print the path and the value.

```js
function iter(object, path) {
    path = path || [];
    Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
        if (typeof object[k] === 'object') {
            iter(object[k], path.concat(k));
            return;
        }
        document.write(path.concat(k).join(' ') + ': ' + object[k] + '<br>');
    });
}

var object = {};

object["abc1"] = {};
object["abc1"]["efg1"] = 123;
object["abc1"]["efg2"] = 124;
iter(object);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(object, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```